# I need to send a static .html file to a angular application from spring boot application and view it in some component

Tags: java, angular, selenium, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am new to angular. 
I have a requirement in which .html report is being generated after running some selenium test cases at my back-end which is a spring-boot application.

Now I need to send this .html report to my UI in order to display the report.

How can I send a .html file from a controller and serve it in my angular application.

Comment: you can do it, just add the returned HTML in an `iframe` and display after sanitizing the same

Comment: How can I get the file from the springboot app??? Displaying is not a concern right now.

Comment: send it as response data from some service call.

Comment: how to send as response data from service call???? response data won't be json in this case so what will be the response type???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple approaches that you could take in such a situation.Abviously the best approach i believe is to have a rest endpoint to return the test results as json and render the test result on the ui side using angular.Other approach include :

- If your html is static one add it to the springboot static folder and
  on the ui part redirect the url to the name of the html so that the
  browser will fetch the html from springboot.
- Another approach in case of dynamic content is that you could return
  the html as response string and inject it into a div using
  angular.

Comment: thank you or your answer. I was checking if its possible to return the html as response. Because it seems rest controller doesn't support it.

Comment: No, a rest controller will return a JSON

Comment: so how should i return this html page to angular server or how should my angular app get access to this html page present inside spring-boot